# prestashop 1.7 stop redirecting cart to checkout

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop-1.7

When customers accidentally add more items to cart. It's impossible to remove some items because if clicked on cart, it redirects to checkout. How to stop redirect?

Answer (score 0):

It was the klarna payment module which was overwriting the default view cart behaviour. After disabling klarna override, it works.